# how to fix the correct url in the button of email laravel notification?

Tags: laravel

i'm using laravel mail notification and i have problem in the url button i have http://127.0.0.1 instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000 and when i clic at the button in email i redirected in failued url because :8000
is missed.

how i can fix this problem please ?

this my code in notification class

````
    <?php
namespace App\Notifications;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\BroadcastMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
class NewProject extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;
    public $data;
    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data=$data;
    }
    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }
    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
        ->line('New Project :' . $this->data['projet'])
        ->action('New project', url('/detail/'.$this->data['id']))
        ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }
    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
        //
        ];
    }
}```
````

Comment: What is your `APP_URL` set to in your `.env` file?

Comment: i change it  APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000 and i execute php artisan config;cache and still the same problem any idea please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base app URL is configured inside the `.env` file on the variable `APP_URL`. So you must set:

```
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

In your environment file.

Comment: i change it and i execute php artisan config;cache and still the same problem any idea please ?