# Verification link in Lavarel CMS

Tags: php, email, content-management-system

Everytime when i send a verification link on email. The button contains the wrong link. For example my sub-domain for the website is hosting.example.com but when i click the verification button it sends me to bot.example.com/Is... but it should to example.com/email/verify/.....
So you can verify only by copying the actual text not clicking the bottom link.

Is there any way of fixing this?
[The email that contains the links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2iwH.png)

I tried googling it and asking on official server. Nobody had the anwser..

Comment: What framework are you using? This looks like a Laravel email. If so, you need to set APP_URL in your `.env`, most likely.

Comment: The URL pulls from either the config or from the URL you're viewing the site at. Check the `APP_URL` in your `.env` file as well as the URL setting in `config/app.php`

Comment: BTW, Laravel itself isn't a CMS, it's just a framework that you can build your own CMS with

Comment: The cms im using is Control Panel that connects to Pterodactyl, and no matter what cms its always if on lavarel then its same link problem

Comment: The app url is set to https://hosting.example.com

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to fix the correct url in the button of email laravel notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61936720/how-to-fix-the-correct-url-in-the-button-of-email-laravel-notification)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i got the anwser thanks to aynber

The problem was in config/app.php i had the url as http://localhost
Thanks to everyone else too!